# how to animate opening of dialog in flutter?

Tags: flutter

hello I want to animate open of dialog in flutter. what I want is when the user click button the dialog start to popping from the button. I want to know if someone has already done it or know how to do it. then it will be very helpful.

Comment: already go through that answer but not found it very helpful.

Comment: I closed the post because I found it duplicate, please add more detail to your post, and I'll be happy to reopen it.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57133640/7666442

Comment: @CopsOnRoad please also add this in duplicate list : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57133640/7666442